# Ubuntu ssh: Could not resolve hostname myserver: Name or service not known

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying login from local machine to aws ubuntu server but I'm unable to login on aws ubuntu server with hostname.

ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@myserver

Getting below error:

ssh: Could not resolve hostname myserver: Name or service not known

I'm able to login with public IP of this server without any issue.

for example:

ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@1.2.3.4

I have changed the hostname with below commands.

1) sudo vim /etc/hosts

2) 127.0.0.1 localhost myserver

3) sudo hostnamectl set-hostname myserver

used the below link to change hostname.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/linux-static-hostname/

How can login on aws ubuntu server with hostname instead of IP address?

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that your local computer do not know myserver.
So you have several option:

1.) You can edit your local /etc/hosts
and set there the public IP to myserver, but than you need to do it on all computer which should access myserver

2.) If you are own a domain, you can set the public IP of your server to myserver.mydomain.com in your DNS configuration.

3.) You can also set myserver in .ssh/config

```
Host myserver
         Hostname ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
         IdentityFile /Users/TNowak/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, 
Thank you for reply.  
I followed the first step now I'm able to login.

Thanks again.